# Do players make rolls with the dice simultaneously or just make a mad dash of individual rolls?

Tags: escape-the-curse-of-the-temple

When the players begin rolling in Escape: The Curse of the Temple, do they all pick up the dice they want to roll and roll all at once, then wait for everyone to be ready to roll before all rolling again, or does everyone just roll as fast as they can on their own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first paragraph of the rules answers your question. [Emphasis in original]

> **Escape** is a real-time board game. Instead of playing the game in rounds, each player rolls his five dice as **quickly** and as **often** as he can without waiting for his teammates!

You can see this in this [game play video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rG2znnjdKYQ&feature=youtu.be&t=84).

[I just picked the first video returned by Google. I haven't reviewed it for quality. I set the start time to a spot where the player on the right rolls dice twice in the time the player on the left rolls the dice once.]

Comment: Ah thanks, I was thrown by the audio intro segment where the narrator says "During the course of the game, you will roll your dice constantly and simultaneously...."